# How to use signature-pad in Ionic3?

Tags: angular, ionic3, signaturepad

I am new to ionic 3. We are using signature tag we are geting the error:

1. nav-controller-base.js:88Failed to navigate:  Template parse errors:
       'signature-pad' is not a known element:
        1. If 'signature-pad' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
        2. If 'signature-pad' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this
   component to suppress this message

---

```
ionic info
Cordova CLI: 6.3.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v6.0.0
Xcode version: Not installed

 <ion-col>
         <signature-pad   minWidth=2 canvasWidth=400 canvasHeight=200      backgroundColor='#f6fbff'penColor= '#666a73'(onBeginEvent)="drawStart()" (onEndEvent)="drawComplete()">
      </signature-pad>
 </ion-col>


app.module.ts
  @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage,
        SignaturePading
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
        SignaturePadModule
      ],
      bootstrap: [IonicApp],
      entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage,
        SignaturePading
      ],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
      ]
    })
```

Comment: Can you add app.module.ts to the question?

Comment: @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    SignaturePading
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    SignaturePadModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    SignaturePading
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})

Comment: are you using this in a lazy loaded page?

Comment: no  iam using  other page

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://devdactic.com/signature-drawpad-ionic-2/